# Use JSON url to navigate/push to page

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am working on an ionic2 app.
    I have a JSON file that I am using and I want to set a type or URL param which I can use it for each element in the list, to navigate to a specific page in ionic2.
    I tried something like: `[navPush]="{{ data.url }}"` but that does not work.
    Also tried something like: `(click)="gotopage({{data.url}})"` but that does not work either.

I want to be able to set the page that I want to navigate to dynamically (read from a JSON), instead using separate functions for each item in the list

like:

```
gotoPage() {
    this.nav.push(PagetoNavigateTo);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ionic provides a good example for this. Just create a new project like this: `ionic start name sidemenu` (or manually select the template sidemenu).

In `app.component.ts` you will find a example JSON array `pages` and a function called `openPage()`. You can use it for your own project.

Or you can look right [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-sidemenu/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts), in the GitHub repository.

If you want to use `strings` for page navigation, you need to lazy load your pages. Here a quick tutorial on how to lazy load a page:

1. Remove all page declarations and imports from `app.module.ts` and `app.component.ts`.
2. You will need to create a `module.ts` for every page you have (for example `home.module.ts`). They could look like this:

`home.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage)
  ],
  exports: [
    HomePage
  ]
})

export class HomeModule {}
```

3. Now you are ready to go, just change `rootPage:any = HomePage` to `rootPage:string = 'HomePage` in `app.component.ts`

Now you can just use a function like `openPage()` to navigate through your app:

```
public openPage (name: string) : void {
  this.nav.setRoot(name);
}
```

Comment: This does not help. First of all it uses a static object there as page. and "*ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">" my situation is (click)="openPage('data.url'), but it gives me: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert

Comment: This error occurs, because you using strings and not components. Where do you get this JSON from? This is only possible when you lazy load your pages. Otherwise you would need to import every single page into the app.

Comment: Yes, I have a json with a data like: 
data{
"component": "PagetoNavigate",
}...
And I can use it only as strings there. I can't set the json as:
"component": PagetoNavigate,
It gives me lint and not valid Json i think so.

I want to find a way really to place the name of the page I want to navigate to in my JSON file, no matter will it use (click) or [navPush] , but I know that I can't mix [] with {{}} operators there, and this is my block.

Comment: Okay, this should be no problem. But, the question is why? Whatever, as I just said. You can lazy load your pages. Then you can use strings for the page navigation. I will update my answer.

Comment: I have a list and 5 different pages for now, so it's not a big issue and need of lazy loading. Just need a way/method how to dynamically tell the click event to load the page that I want to set up from the external json.

The reason "why" is because I want to dynamicly controll page that I want to load for each item list. And I have all the litem list's inside a JSON with own values for title, image, additional info. I think you get my point.

Thanks, I am really stuck on this.

Comment: Yeah, but it is the easiest way to use strings as navigation. I don't think there is another or better solution for this. You will need to lazy load your pages.

Comment: Question. What about my home.ts file ? 
I already have the same:
export class HomePage { ... } as well here,  and some functions ?

Comment: Normally you don't need to do any changes there. After you did the changes aboth, you can just use strings to navigate and some other lazy loading features (but this is a completely different topic).

Comment: Ok I tried. I call the function like :

(click)="openPage(data.url)"

but it says in the console : "Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: HomePage"

I have followed your steps, removed from app.modules and app.component.

In my json its like
"data": 
[...
{
"url": "HomePage",
}
...]

Comment: Does the `HomePage` page is really called `HomePage`? I can't do much without code. Maybe you could provide a JSFiddle or something like this.

Comment: Yes it is. I double checked. I have it as export class HomePage in home.ts.
Maybe I need to import something, or maybe a bad call in "(click)="openPage(data.url)"

Comment: Provide some code and I will look at it, I can't say much about it right now.

Comment: I think that i need to add : 
@IonicPage({ 
  name: 'home-page',
})
before @Component in my home.ts

and than call the function like openPage ('home-page)
But even with this...still does not work.

Something its still wrong.

Comment: The new Ionic page generator does this automatically. Sorry for that.

Comment: I have pushed publicly to this repo: https://github.com/noxiousmobile/ioniclazydemo

This is a starter, with a simple default page and a button, and a homepage done in a way as you suggested above.

I tried both ways of using openPage() with calling  openPage('home-page') and openPage(HomePage) and non works. You can check it out.

Comment: You didn't use my `openPage()` function. If you give him a string and he tries to access it with `page.component`, sure it doesn't work. And you don't need this name in `@IonicPage`. Give him the exported class as string `"HomePage"`. I described everything right.

Comment: I have removed that, and used your approach: http://prntscr.com/g07nmz
I push this to the repo, but i still see this error message.

Comment: Give it as a string in default Page html, please. `openPage('HomePage')`

Comment: ok, I solve it finally. The approach that worked is using as:
(click)="openPage(data.url)" , data.url is taken from the json, by looping using *NgIf

Also the home.module.ts is:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
  ],
  exports: [
    HomePage
  ]
})

export class HomePageModule {}
And than in home.ts I placed:
@IonicPage({
  name: 'home-page',
  segment: 'home'
})

Thank you!